# Short story: pebble-sized galaxy lost on a beach

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story long ago, about a man searching endlessly on a beach for a miniature galaxy he somehow lost.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very (very) terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: HI there. I know you said that's all you can remember, but still, may you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you read that, was it new at the time, was it in an anthology, a magazine?

Comment: Also - did you mean **pebble-sized**? Online dictionary doesn't find a definition, the only "pepple" thing I can find so far is an [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pepple) one.

Comment: This rings a bell. Does the story end with him finding the world and entering it?

Comment: It must have ben 30 years ago or more --- so that would mean the old-time classic SF writers I reckon

Comment: A very similar question has just been asked on rec.arts.sf.written - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.written/eW4EVVotyZQ - with more clues. Does that help anyone?

Comment: Jenayah, in geology, a pebble is a grain from 4 to 64 mm in diameter.

Answer (score 14):

The story is [*Beachcomber*](https://archive.bookfrom.net/damon-knight/306316-the_beachcomber_the_star_beast_and_other_stories.html) (1952) by Damon Knight, available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Imagination_v03n07_1952-12_LennyS-cape1736#page/n75/mode/1up); publication history at [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57061).

It is not the galaxy but the whole Universe, but I don't think there are many stories with *a man endlessly searching on a beach for a miniature cosmic object he somehow lost*.

> The Beachcomber made an impatient gesture. "You don’t think we could bring it back into a space it already occupied, do you? It was in stasis, all but a fraction out of this time-line. Just a miniature left, so that it could be controlled. A model of the universe, so big." He spread his thumb and forefinger
> an inch apart — "Just a pebble."

> Maxwell's jaw dropped open. He stared at the giant. "You don’t mean — you — "

> "Oh, yes," said the Beachcomber, "I landed about twenty miles out from shore — five years ago." He stared out across the sea, while his fingers groped nervously among the pebbles at his feet.

> "And when I hit the water," he said, "I dropped it."

Comment: Regarding Jenayah's question about pebble size, the story specifies: "There were no nice beaches; they were all covered with inch-thick pebbles instead of sand..." As 1 inch = 25.4 mm, this does fall within the pebble size range, at least as defined by geologists.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Jenayah's question was not about the meaning of "pebble-sized" but "pepple-sized" which was in the title of the question before it was edited.

Comment: user14111: Light dawns.