# Short story with a man looking for a shrunk world lost on a beach

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story revolves around a man walking along the sea shore picking up stones and looking at them intensely and them putting them down.

At the end of the story I remember that we found out that he was a space traveler and, to save his world from some disaster, they shrank the world and he was to find a safe  place to restore the world, but he fell to earth and dropped the world in the sea and he was looking for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Beachcomber*](https://archive.bookfrom.net/damon-knight/306316-the_beachcomber_the_star_beast_and_other_stories.html) (1952) by Damon Knight, available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Imagination_v03n07_1952-12_LennyS-cape1736#page/n75/mode/1up); publication history at [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57061).

> The Beachcomber made an impatient gesture. "You don’t think we could bring it back into a space it already occupied, do you? It was in stasis, all but a fraction out of this time-line. Just a miniature left, so that it could be controlled. A model of the universe, so big." He spread his thumb and forefinger an inch apart — "Just a pebble."
>
> Maxwell's jaw dropped open. He stared at the giant. "You don’t mean — you — "
>
> "Oh, yes," said the Beachcomber, "I landed about twenty miles out from shore — five years ago." He stared out across the sea, while his fingers groped nervously among the pebbles at his feet.
>
> "And when I hit the water," he said, "I dropped it."

I remembered that this had appeared on the site before, so I searched for *site:scifi.stackexchange.com short story man searches for world lost on beach*, which brought me to [Short story: pebble-sized galaxy lost on a beach](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211087/short-story-pebble-sized-galaxy-lost-on-a-beach)